# Get all JIRA project versions via SOAP and PHP

Tags: php, soap, jira, soap-client

I've found a lot of examples how to get issues info, but no examples how to get project info such as all available released/unreleased versions, components etc.
Is it possible to get with soap client?

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT rely on SOAP with JIRA.

The [API page](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-api-status/jira-rpc-services/jira-xml-rpc-overview/soap-and-xml-rpc-api-deprecation-notice) says:

> JIRA's SOAP and XML-RPC remote APIs have been deprecated since JIRA
>   6.0 and will be removed in JIRA 7.0.

Use the REST API: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Edit:
To actually answer your question: yes, it should be possible.

But don't invest energy into the research. Right now, standalone JIRA is at 6.4.5, ondemand is at 6.5, I would bet 7.0 comes out this autumn.